# On click file download, on success redirect to another page using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

In my WordPress project, my <kbd>**Download**</kbd> button containing a `.zip` file, which onClick should be downloaded. So the HTML producing is:

```
<a id="732" class="btn btn-default download-link" href="https://example.com/download.zip">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

I'm using AJAX to refresh the download count.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
jQuery(document).on('click', '.download-link', function () {
    var id = this.id;

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {"action": "count_download",
                    "id": id
                },
        success: function (data) {
            window.location = site.url + "/download-success?fid="+ id;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Everything works fine until I added the file with the link. Typically such a link will start downloading the `.zip` file, but even after the time taken by the AJAX call the page redirected to the download-success page without triggering the download.

And it occurs most of the time, only once or twice the file starts downloading.

**P.S.:** I tested [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4373955/1743124) but it's not my case.

Comment: don't do it this way. Serve up the file via a php script, and do the download count update there. It'd be far more reliable: the script will catch **ALL** hits on the file, not just the ones that "politely" went through your html/js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with @marc. Just to add more information, do this.

```
<a href='download.php?file=some_file.zip'>Download</a>
```

Above can be url link to download and below will be php code in download.php

```
//code to update download count (UPDATE tbl_dwn SET total = total + 1)
//below is code to download (hope you know it)
$zipName = $_GET['file']; //here you've to specify the absolute path to the download.zip file
header("Content-type: application/zip");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$zipName."");
header("Content-length: " . filesize($zipName));
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
readfile($zipName);
```

Try out this and let me know if you've any problem.

Comment: Okay, with your suggestion in mind, I can successfully redirecting the page, btw the file downloading is a crap. So, I'm using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20731595/1743124) bunch of code, but before getting into it, I tried: `echo $file; if(file_exists($file)){ echo $file; }`, where `$file` is showing https://github.com/nanodesigns/wp-adzonia/archive/v1.2.zip, but the `file_exists()` is showing error: *`Warning: file_exists(): Unable to find the wrapper &quot;https&quot; - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?`*

Comment: `$_GET['file']` must be protected against unsecure inputs!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Will take you to another page

```
success: function (data) {
    window.location.href = site.url + "/download-success?fid="+ id;
}
```

Will take you to another page in the new window

```
success: function (data) {
    window.open('site.url + "/download-success?fid="+ id');
}
```