# How to differentiate a URL is on server or off server (remote)?

Tags: php, download, server

I'm taking user input of their downloadable files, where they can be uploaded-

- to their own server (i.e.: `example.com/files/filename.ext`)
- or, to a remote one. (i.e.: `external.org/someone/somewhere/filename.ext`)

As I's [trying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27928098/1743124) implementing a download button (with some process), then I [came to know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9730392) that file downloading from remote server is not like so. That's why I need to check whether a URL is of my own server or from an external one.

If I can differentiate between both then with a simple conditional I can pass the flow to whether:

- an [on server way](http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/download.php)
- or, [an off server way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27928098/1743124)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get hostname from file URL and compare with your web hostname

```
$fileHost = parse_url("example.com/files/filename.ext", PHP_URL_HOST);
//$fileHost == "example.com"
if($fileHost == $myHost)
{
    //this is local file
}
else
{
    //this is external file
}
```

you can let your PHP to get $myHost with

```
$myHost = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php